# How to access a modal dialog box which opens after clicking a link through Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am new to Python. I am trying to scrape the data from indiegogo website.
I am not able to scrape data from the modal dialog box/pop-up window that opens when I click the About link of the creator.

https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/camp-pride-needs-your-support#/

I have tried

1) `browser.switch_to.alert()`

2) `browser.switch_to.frame()`

3) `browser.switch_to.window()`

but no luck.

Part of my code is

```
        window_before = browser.window_handles[0]
        about=browser.find_element_by_class_name("campaignTrust- detailsLinks-info.ng-binding")

        about.click()

        #window_after = browser.window_handles[1]

        iframe = browser.find_element_by_class_name("modal-dialog")

        #alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
        time.sleep(5)
        #browser.switch_to.window(window_after)
        #browser.switch_to.alert().accept()
        #alert.accept()
        browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        #print (browser.page_source.encode("utf_8","ignore"))
        creator_role=soup.find("div", class_="campaignTrustInfo-campaignerDetails-role.ng-binding").get_text()
        info_abtpage=soup.find("div", class_="campaignTrustInfo-sectionContent ng-binding")
```

Comment: `soup` isn't getting set in your example above. In general, you can't mix BeautifulSoup and selenium.

Comment: once I get access to the frame/poop-up then I want to scrape data from that so I am using soup but I am not able to get control over the pop up that is being opened

Comment: I understand, but you've not initialized `soup` to anything yet in your code above.... Since you're using selenium, you can use selenium to get text instead of soup. For example: `creator_role = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.campaignTrustInfo-campignerDetails-role.ng-binding').text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup you're looking at isn't a window, an iframe or a browser alert: it's just more DOM.

You're using selenium, so keep this simple and don't switch over to use BeautifulSoup.

```
browser.get('https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/camp-pride-needs-your-support')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.campaignTrust-detailsLinks-info.ng-binding').click()
info = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.modal-content').text
```

And you'll get text with embedded newlines:

> About
>   J Mase III
>   Camp Pride....

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its giving me all the text in it but I want to scrape the data in csv file so I want individual field from it as Creator Role, Campaigns Created etc.I cant do that if I just extract text.

Comment: I also want to click on View full Profile Link in there

Comment: To get the full profile link, do another `find_element...().click()`. This will bring up a new window, so do the `window_handles()` bit you've done before to "find" the window, and then `switch_to_window()`

Comment: Thanks for the information and your time.I am able to proceed further .